# falcon api to execute the tasks from celery

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, falcon

task.py file

```
from time import sleep

import celery


app = celery.Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    """
    :param int x:
    :param int y:
    :return: int
    """
    # sleep just for demonstration
    sleep(5)

    return x + y
```

my falcon app.py file

```
import json
import requests
import falcon
from tasks import add
from celery.result import AsyncResult
import falcon
import json
class StartTask(object):

    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        # start task
        data = json.loads(req.stream.read().decode('UTF-8'))

        print "got request"

        task = add.delay(data['add_one'], data['add_two'])
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        # return task_id to client
        result = {'task_id': task.id}
        resp.body = json.dumps(result)


class TaskStatus(object):

    def on_get(self, req, resp, task_id):
        # get result of task by task_id and generate content to client
        task_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
        result = {'status': task_result.status, 'result': task_result.result}
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.body = json.dumps(result)


app = falcon.API()

# registration of routes
app.add_route('/start_task', StartTask())
app.add_route('/task_status/{task_id}', TaskStatus())
```

external api will pass the params to execute the task or any other method suggested will be appricated
now this purely on post call how can i do it on get method in falcon
I have another

```
import json
import requests
import falcon
from tasks import add
from celery.result import AsyncResult
import falcon
import json

class JSON_Middleware(object):
    def process_request(self, req, resp):
        raw_json = json.loads(req.stream.read().decode('UTF-8'))
        print req.content_length
        return raw_json

class Test:
    def on_post(self,req,resp):
        print raw_json
        pass

app = application = falcon.API(middleware=JSON_Middleware())
t = Test()
app.add_route('/test',t)
```

how can i use the raw_json on post or am i doing it in a worng way not sure

Thanks for Viewing and Thanks a ton for Answering
Regards 
Newbee

Comment: can you please clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish? It's not clear from your post

Comment: trying to run task with api

Comment: Celery uses a message broker to communicate between the master process and workers. Are you using rabbitmq? You should try sending a message from your API route to celery that triggers the task.

Comment: Sending api to triggers the tasks